# Как определить какой браузер использует пользователь - Chrome или Chromium?

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью javascript определить использует пользователь google chrome или chromium?

Answer (score 2):

Браузер Chrome поставляется со встроенным ридером PDF, Chromium - нет.
Это можно проверить используя JavaScript:

```js
function isWithChromePDFReader() {   
  for (var i = 0; i < navigator.plugins.length; i++) { 
    if (navigator.plugins[i].name == 'Chrome PDF Viewer') {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

function checkBrowserPlugin() {
  var isChrome = window.chrome,
    winNav = window.navigator,
    vendorName = winNav.vendor,
    isOpera = winNav.userAgent.indexOf("OPR") > -1,
    isIEedge = winNav.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1;
    
  if (isChrome !== null &&
    typeof isChrome !== "undefined" &&
    vendorName === "Google Inc." &&
    isOpera === false &&
    isIEedge === false) {
    if (isWithChromePDFReader()) {
      alert('With PDF-Reader (Chrome)');
    } else {
      alert('Without PDF-Reader (Chromium)');
    }
  } else {
    alert('It is not Chrome or Chromium');
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="checkBrowserPlugin();"> Check </button>
```

Этот метод не является надежным на все 100%, так как пользователи могут копировать PDF-ридер из Chrome в свой каталог Chromium, смотрите [Why doesn't Chromium have “Chrome PDF Viewer” plugin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12584/why-doesnt-chromium-have-chrome-pdf-viewer-plugin/135985#135985)

Между Chromium и Chrome практически нет разницы, причём некоторые браузеры используют движок Chromium (какая-то старая версия Opera к примеру).

Ссылка на источник:

- [How do I detect Chromium specifically vs. Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17279993/5275890)

Также будет полезно:

- [JavaScript: How to find out if the user browser is Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13348618/5275890)

Answer (score 0):

На Ubuntu Mate оба браузера выдают разный User-Agent, не думаю, чтобы на винде они отличались?

Chromium:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/63.0.3239.84 Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36
```

Chrome:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
var isFirefox = /Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent);



console.log(isChrome);
console.log(isFirefox);
console.log(navigator.vendor); 
console.log(navigator.userAgent);
```

Comment: Открыл в своём Chromium, выдало true

Comment: @andreymal в каком браузере?

Comment: Говорю же, Chromium